# Confused on how to use label encoded values with original values

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning

Hi i am trying to work on a ML project where the data set contains both numeric and alphabetic values. I used `LabelEncoder()` from sklearn to convert alphabetic values to numeric successfully but i am unable to add all required values in the "X" "y" variables.
here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
data = pd.read_csv('data-set.csv')

num_val = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
gender = num_val.fit_transform(list(data['gender']))
ever_married = num_val.fit_transform(list(data['ever_married']))
work_type = num_val.fit_transform(list(data['work_type']))
Residence_type = num_val.fit_transform(list(data['Residence_type']))
smoking_status = num_val.fit_transform(list(data['smoking_status']))

predict = "stroke"

X = list(zip(gender,ever_married,work_type,Residence_type,smoking_status))
y = data['stroke']

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1)

model = SVC()

model.fit(X_train, y_train)

pred = model.predict(X_test)

acc = accuracy_score(y_test, pred)
print(acc)
```

The data set i used [is here](https://www.kaggle.com/fedesoriano/stroke-prediction-dataset)

How can i add all the values in 'X' variable and other values in the data set all together(both changed values and unchanged numeric values.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Pandas [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) with a function (`transform` in the example below) with the same code you already have, but using the list of `columns` that you want to transform over the original dataframe (`data`). Next, drop the target column from the dataframe (`stroke` in this particular dataset) to create the `X` variable. You also have to fill the `bmi` NaN values with something relevant to your analysis, otherwise the `fit` function will raise a `ValueError`.

```py
...
data = pd.read_csv('healthcare-dataset-stroke-data.csv')
print(data.head())

def transform(series):
    num_val = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    np_array = num_val.fit_transform(list(series))
    return pd.Series(np_array)

t_list = ["gender","ever_married","work_type","Residence_type","smoking_status"]

data[t_list] = data[t_list].apply(transform)
print(data.head())

predict = "stroke"

X = data.drop(columns=['stroke'])
# fill "bmi" NaN values with something relevant to your analysis
X = X.fillna(X.median())
y = data['stroke']

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1)
...
```

Original dataframe

```py
      id  gender   age  ...     work_type Residence_type  avg_glucose_level   bmi   smoking_status  stroke
0   9046    Male  67.0  ...       Private          Urban             228.69  36.6  formerly smoked       1
1  51676  Female  61.0  ... Self-employed          Rural             202.21   NaN     never smoked       1
2  31112    Male  80.0  ...       Private          Rural             105.92  32.5     never smoked       1
3  60182  Female  49.0  ...       Private          Urban             171.23  34.4           smokes       1
4   1665  Female  79.0  ... Self-employed          Rural             174.12  24.0     never smoked       1
```

Transformed dataframe

```py
      id  gender   age  ... work_type  Residence_type  avg_glucose_level   bmi  smoking_status  stroke
0   9046       1  67.0  ...         2               1             228.69  36.6               1       1
1  51676       0  61.0  ...         3               0             202.21   NaN               2       1
2  31112       1  80.0  ...         2               0             105.92  32.5               2       1
3  60182       0  49.0  ...         2               1             171.23  34.4               3       1
4   1665       0  79.0  ...         3               0             174.12  24.0               2       1
```